# Framerate Bottleneck With GTX 560 TI 448

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, gaming, framerate

I recently upgraded from an old Nvidia GTX 9800+ to a GTX 560 TI 448. However, I'm getting much lower framerates than I'd expected based on benchmarks run by other 560 TI 448 owners. Specifically, in Battlefield 3, I can run Ultra on 30-40 FPS at 1600x900, but that's not the main issue. On low settings, at the same resolution, I'm getting framerate dips into the mid-low 30s and even in the 20's occasionally. I've got the card currently clocked at 931 Core/2155 Memory and voltage at 1.150. I'm guessing that it's not the GPU causing me to get huge framerate spikes on minimum settings. My system is fairly old, but it meets recommended settings. I've listed the major parts below:

- CPU: Intel Q8300 @ 2.5Ghz (Yorkfield, Quad-core)
- RAM: 8 GB DDR2 (Generic)
- GPU: EVGA GTX 560 TI 448 Ultra Classified Edition @ 931/2155/1.150V
- PSU: Rosewill Capstone 750 Watt

Can anyone tell me what's causing these framerate spikes?

Comment: What's the version on the GeForce driver you're using?

Comment: I've tried both the newest stable and beta drivers, right now I'm using 310.64. I get the same problem with both.